# Mysql query using values of an other query

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
select * 
  from Tb_Octa_Maanden 
 where tMaand >= 'YYY' 
   and tMaand < '202006' 
   and tMaand not in 
      (select left(tDatum,6) 
         from Tb_Betalingen 
        where ID_Dienst = ZZZ 
          and tType = 'PASSIEF')
```

The YYY and ZZZ are the results of an other query:

```
select IntID_Dienst as ZZZ
     , left(tDatumStart,6) as YYY 
  from Tb_Dienst D 
 where IntID_TypeDienst in ('248','274')
```

Can I do this in just one query?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). You might also like to familiarise yourself with JOINs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Tb_Octa_Maanden 
WHERE 
  tMaand >= COALESCE(
    (SELECT 
      LEFT(tDatumStart,6) 
      FROM Tb_Dienst D 
      WHERE IntID_TypeDienst IN ('248','274') 
      LIMIT 1
    ),
    '000000'
  )
  AND
  tMaand < '202006' 
  AND
  tMaand NOT IN (
    SELECT LEFT(tDatum,6) 
    FROM Tb_Betalingen 
    WHERE 
      ID_Dienst IN 
        (SELECT IntID_Dienst 
        FROM Tb_Dienst D 
        WHERE IntID_TypeDienst IN ('248','274')) 
      AND
      tType = 'PASSIEF'
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because de query uses 2 times 
SELECT IntID_Dienst 
        FROM Tb_Dienst D 
        WHERE IntID_TypeDienst IN ('248','274')
The 2 values should come from the same record every time.

It should also be possible to access te values of Tb_Dienst

I could make a loop in php with table Tb_Dienst and make a query every time with those 2 values, but I think/hope this would be possible in 1 query.